В боте telebot/python перестало работать приветствие в больших группах, в маленьких работает, что не так?
В большой телеграм группе бот telebot/python перестал получать @bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members']), при этом в группах поменьше он работает, как это исправить?
Вот код:
from telebot import TeleBot
bot=TeleBot(API)
@bot.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
def handle_new_members(m):
print('ok')
bot.polling()


Проблема в том, что при большом количестве участников, тг см перестает присылать сообщения о том, что кто-то вступил в группу. И больший, довольно относительное понятие. Такие может быть и при  50 человек, а то и меньше. Попробуйте использовать объект ChatMemberUpdated
